# Translate $\text{EF}\:p$ to LTL

Tags: logic

I have read that the [CTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic) formula $\text{EF}\:p$ can't be translated to [LTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic), but I don't understand why $\neg \text{G} \neg p$ is not a correct translation.

Answer (score 1):

$\text {EF}p$ reads "it is possible that some day $p$", while $\lnot \text G \lnot p$" reads "not always not $p$".

The second one is equivalent "some day $p$" and there is no expression here of "possibility", that means that maybe $p$ will hold or maybe not.

---

The issue is that [LTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) is *linear* (no branching) whilt [CTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic) "is a branching-time logic, meaning that its model of time is a tree-like structure in which the future is not determined".

Comment: But $\text {EF}p$ will be false if $\text{p}$ never occurs. It means that there exists a path on which $\text{p}$ occurs at some point. So how does it express 'possibility'?

Comment: @root - no; possibility does not implies existence. Possible means it is **not** necessary **not**.